# How to manage big spikes of connections to RabbitMQ

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

Our rabbitmq server can't keep up with connections when we have spikes above 3000 connections/second, and new connections take long to stablish (reaching 3s limit we have for failing). We need publishers to return fast as any delay transmit to user experience.

We are currently looking at coding a load balance of connections to a second rabbitmq server as a fast temporal solution.

We only create the connection when we need to publish, and we reuse the same connection and channel for the same web request/process as best practices suggest. The nature of the PHP process is to die after the web request.

Can I reuse the connection to publish between web requests?

Is a 3000 connection/s spike enough to make the rabbitmq server suffer from a tpc connection overload?

What direction should we take when we have 10x this connections in the future?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [amqproxy](https://github.com/cloudamqp/amqproxy). It will let you re-use connections.

If you want to "10x" this you can create edge-node RabbitMQ servers that uses a shovel to move the messages from the edge nodes to a Central cluster where consumers are connected.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I'm going forward with amqproxy and I'll study this edge-nod RabbitMQ.

Comment: @jrhoding this really was game changer and the site stability improved a lot adding the amqproxy. But we are reaching peaks of 56k connections, I believe we run out of ports and the proxy starts refusing new connections. We are planning to use ha proxy and load balance between different amqproxy servers. Do you think it's a good idea?

Comment: I'll have to admit that I'm not sure how the layout of your architecture is right now. But you should be able to up the ulimit for the proxy to handle more connections. If possible draw an architecture diagram and upload as a ticket on https://github.com/cloudamqp/amqproxy and we can advise from there, as the conversation is straying from the original question.